# Android: [AxiosError: Network Error] Expo React Native

Tags: android, react-native, networking, axios, expo

Relevant modules used:

- "expo": "~46.0.9"
- "axios": "^0.27.2"

I'm trying to fetch some data, everything works just fine on iOS devices but the problem comes when using an Android, the network fails for some reason:

```
Android Running app on sdk_gphone64_arm64
[AxiosError: Network Error]
```

Here's the line of code that causes it:

```
const { data } = await axios.get('http:<my IP or 'localhost'>:<port>/endpoint');
```

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The solution for this was that Axios didn't really need my real IP address. It needed the IP that expo gives you when you start the metro bundler.

So instead of:

```
axios.get('http:<my IP or 'localhost'>:<port>/endpoint')
```

I changed it for:

```
axios.get('http:192.168.100.20:<port>/endpoint')
```

Now it is working.